# Show entry on certain date, regardless of year

Tags: entries, postdate

A project I'm working on needs to show a daily reading depending on the date you access the page. I plan to create entries for each day of the year, and each year it will show the post for that day.

For example, I'll create an entry with a post date of May 1, 2015. That entry should show on May 1, 2016/2017/2018, etc.

I've tried only putting in MM-DD in the postDate parameter, but no luck; that throws a PHP error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this is not possible with a simple `postDate` parameter and you have to find a workaround.
The Twig apporach would be to loop all events and filter the right ones with a simple conditional.

```
{% set events = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null).order('postDate asc') %}
{% for event in events %}
    {% if event.postDate|date('m-d') == now|date('m-d') %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you'd like to paginate the results, collect / merge entry IDs within the for loop first and
then prepare another ElementCriteriaModel with these IDs in its `id` param, to get the entries.